# How to create a 2d jelly/soft/blob body?

Tags: unity, 2d

I'm a developer looking into game development. I have an idea that requires a 'character' that needs a jelly like body. I've found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_FqZrOPsB8) which really demonstrates what I want.

I've looked around and there are libraries/assets that do this (like Jelly Sprites) but none state **how** they do it, and that's what I'm interrested in.

What I've read so far is that **a** way of doing it is using multiple rigid bodies joined with joints that don't collide with each other. Witht he common sidenote that it might not perform that well.

I'm hoping anyone has any pointers or tutorials that explain the concepts of jelly/soft/blob bodies. Any pointers towards achieving the effect shown in the video would be awesome.

Comment: Soft bodies are essentially made using spring-mass systems. You could look at this paper for a detailed explanation: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef27/ec3ae925849e43c7a1cca54cf026b3699679.pdf

Comment: @Hermetix thanks for the info! Do you have any info on collision detection and making sure the GameObject looks like one object tot he player when using this technique?